# Issue with merging flowfiles on distributed nifi cluster & email notification

Tags: apache-nifi

I am on Nifi 1.5 version with 5 nodes in nifi cluster and I am trying to implement centralize flow monitoring using `SiteToSiteBulletinReportingTask` and `SiteToSiteStatusReportingTask` . Conceptual idea is to have reporting tasks send bulletins and statuses to common port and use `QueryRecord` processor to detect specific events & send email to team. For e.g. event like ' is backpressure enabled?' using query - `"select * from FLOWFILE where isBackPressureEnabled='true'"`

But the problem I am running into is, since its 5 node cluster, any time a event occurs for a component (for e.g. connection) , all of five nodes reports the same event. So I have 5 flowfiles distributed on 5 nodes coming thru reporting task. Hence , my `putEmail` processor sends 5 emails for same event. This can be bit annoying.

So far the flow looks like -

```
`InputPort` -> 
`SplitJson` ->
`EvaluateJson` -> // to differentiate between status &
                    bulletin messages since its a older version 
                    of nifi which doesnt have reporting.task.type 
                    attribute
 RouteOnAttribute ->  
 QueryRecord -> 
 MergeContent -> // here I tried to merge with correlation 
                   attribute as componentId hoping it will 
                   merge all similar flowfiles together for same component
 PutEmail
```

I have tried MergeRecord,MergeContent with execute on Primary only,PartitionRecord and then merge. Even tried `GROUP BY` clause on `QueryRecord` processor. But none of my strategies are yielding a single flowfile which will only trigger one email.

How do achieve sending only single email for same event for same component. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by writing all event flowfiles from all nodes into one common HDFS path and then using `ListHDFS` + `FetchHDFS` on `Primary Node` only. This allowed me to grab all events on only one node, deduplicate all repeated events and send email only once.

Answer (score 0):

If you can upgrade to 1.8 or newer, then you could use a load-balanced connection with strategy set to "single node", this way can converge everything after the InputPort to a single node and then your QueryRecord and MergeContent would have access to all flow files.

Comment: Thank you Bryan but this is enterprise level cluster and not something I have control over.